# Why does Phabricator still warn me:PHP Extension 'APC' Not Installed

Tags: phabricator

I've installed APC 3.1.13 via PECL on CentOS 7. Everything seems OK.

`php -i | grep apc` output:

```
Additional .ini files parsed => /etc/php.d/apcu.ini,
apc
apcu
MMAP File Mask => /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.coredump_unmap => Off => Off
apc.enable_cli => Off => Off
apc.enabled => On => On
apc.entries_hint => 4096 => 4096
apc.gc_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.mmap_file_mask => /tmp/apc.XXXXXX => /tmp/apc.XXXXXX
apc.preload_path => no value => no value
apc.rfc1867 => Off => Off
apc.rfc1867_freq => 0 => 0
apc.rfc1867_name => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS => APC_UPLOAD_PROGRESS
apc.rfc1867_prefix => upload_ => upload_
apc.rfc1867_ttl => 3600 => 3600
apc.serializer => php => php
apc.shm_segments => 1 => 1
apc.shm_size => 32M => 32M
apc.slam_defense => On => On
apc.smart => 0 => 0
apc.ttl => 0 => 0
apc.use_request_time => On => On
apc.writable => /tmp => /tmp
```

but Phabricator's issue lists still warn me: `PHP Extension 'APC' Not Installed`. Is it a false message? What can I do about it?

Comment: Since it wasn't mentioned in your question, I'm going to ask... Have you restarted Apache?  

Most of my experience is with Gentoo, not CentOS.  In Gentoo, there are separate php.ini files for Apache and CLI.  That command will show the command line, you may want to check if there is a separate php.ini for Apache.

Comment: @CEPA I've restarted my machine and still no good.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have enabled it in your Apache config

On my box its:
`/etc/php5/apache2/conf.d/20-apcu.ini`

Running php -i is simply the command line interface, Apache loads it's own extensions.

Comment: It's Apache module. Does cli cause this? How can I turn it On?